# Collecting payments for mobile web apps

Tags: mobile, web, payment

Bonus! 2 questions in 1:

1. We're building a mobile web app (not native) and would like to be able to collect payment for a real-world service. Since it's a mobile web app, we had assumed we wouldn't be restricted to any of the native in-app payments that Apple and Android impose, right?
2. Are there any services for CC payments? Even nicer would be one where the user could snap a pic of their CC and the app would capture their billing info and submit payment.

Answer (score 0):

1) There's no restriction from Apple to web apps.

2) PayPal provides you the possibility to process payments from the web. It provides you a lot of ways to integrate payments to your website. For example, it redirects the customer after they place the purchase. And there's also IPN, which notifies a page of your website that a payment was placed and which items were bought.

paypal.com

Comment: Thanks, Fernando. PayPal redirecting is a concern to us. Any other services that would process the payment in the background and leave the user in the web app?

Comment: I don't know any other that I trust. :(